# Does wtforms Integer Field force a new line when displayed on webpage?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am using wtforms as part of a Python + Flask project.  There are some cases where I want multiple fields of a form to appear on the same line on the webpage.  With SelectField, this works as expected.  However, when I use IntegerField, it seems to automatically create a new line after the field is displayed, and I get have more than one on a line.

The Form:

```
class PremiumMandatory(FlaskForm):
    match_dol = IntegerField('Dollar')
    match_per = IntegerField('Percent')
```

The .html

```
{{form.match_dol.label}}
${{form.match_dol(size=3)}}

&nbsp
{{form.match_per(size=3)}}%
{% for error in form.match_per.errors %}
```

Using the above, the two fields also appear on different lines on the webpage.  Ho do I keep then on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

This is an entirely HTML/CSS problem. There are many ways to put multiple fields of a form on the same line, for example, you could use [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), which is very easy to use.

Another simple way is:

```html
<form>
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                {{ form.match_dol.label }}
                {{ form.match_dol(size=3) }}
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                {{ form.match_per.label }}
                {{ form.match_per(size=3) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I determined the issue was related to the way I was doing error processing on those inputs.  I will still try the grid system as you suggest as that will improve the overall look.